# IntelliJ Idea 2018.2 no option for importing gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

When I attempt to open a build.gradle I get an error saying "cannot import anything from ~/path/to/build.gradle". When in look at the build tools available for IntelliJ, gradle does not show up in the list:
[image]

I definitely have gradle installed:
[image]

Comment: Do you have IntelliJ's Gradle plugin installed?

Comment: No Gradle plugin, no Gradle support...that's all. For me it works out of the box. Did you try to restart the IDE and reimport the project?

Comment: I had the plugin installed, but not enabled. That checkbox is very hard to see, especially if you don't know that it exists! Thank you for your comments.

Comment: You should not be asking product related questions here. Rather read the installation manual or usage manual for it.

Answer (score 6):

I did not enable the gradle plugin. I assumed that having it installed automatically enabled it, which was a poor assumption. Below is what an enabled plugin looks like:
[image]

Comment: This is infuriating. I've spent an hour looking for the reason. Thank you.

Comment: super annoying that you have to click to enable gradle. Ah well. Thanks for the tip, saved me a ton of frustration.